# Storing check boxes in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am having issues figuring out how to store marked check boxes in local storage, and have them refresh on a separate page.

Here is my javascript on the first page with the check boxes.

```
function storemyform(){ 
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox1_0'));
if (checked == true)
{
document.getElementById("checkbox1_0").checked = true;
}
```

Here is my HTML for that page

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <legend>Option</legend>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_0" class="custom" value="" />
      <label for="checkbox1_0">Option</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_1" class="custom" value="" />
      <label for="checkbox1_1">Option</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom" value="" />
      <label for="checkbox1_2">Option</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_3" class="custom" value="" />
      <label for="checkbox1_3">Option</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_4" class="custom" value="" />
      <label for="checkbox1_4">Option</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
```

And here is my load function on a separate page

```
function getmynote(){
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox1_0'));
document.getElementById("checkbox1_0").checked = checked;
}
```

I am at a total loss to what I am doing wrong. I know this has been answered before but I am just not "getting it" Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is `storemyform` called ?

Comment: Will your app be non-functional if localstorage is not available?  Is that acceptable?

Comment: I have other localstorage that is working, just not the check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any code that would store the check state in localStorage, only code that reads the check state.

In your function `storemyform` you need to make use of `localStorage.setItem(name, value)`.

Comment: I guess this is why I am so lost. I guess I am not really sure how to approach it.

Comment: Added some help to my answer.